# Understanding angular module imports

Tags: angular, module

Im working on a legacy library which uses in some of its components FormsModules functionalities, so FormsModule is imported at the level of LibraryModule like so:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LabelButtonPrimaryComponent,
        TextAreaComponent,
        TextInputComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ]})
 export class IronFrameworkModule { }
```

When i bluid/pack the library, and then install it in some other angular application i still need to import FormsModule in the Application AppModule in order for the components in the IronLibrary to work.

Why is that?

Comment: Is your `IronFrameworkModule` imported in youri `AppModule`? Check you are not using `FormsModule` elswhere.

Comment: It is. Im not using any FormsModule functionality else where

Answer (score 1):

A `Module` in order to be seen and used by others `Module`, it need to be import in the @NgModule class decorator, and it only visible to that module, so in your case the `FormModule` only visible to `IronFrameworkModule`, but not be seen by the `AppModule`.You then have two option:

1. Like you did : import the `FormModule` to your `AppModule` so it is
   now seen by `AppModule`
2. Export the `FormModule` from your `IronFrameworkModule` so
       whichever `Module` import `IronFrameworkModule`, the
       `FormModule`will also be visible to them for use

Alternatively, you should create a [`Shared Module`](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) contain all the Module, Components, Directive ... which would be reused. Then you only need to import that module to others, it centralized the code, so it more easy to maintain.

Comment: I see. I thought that, like only IronFramework needs the FormsModule functionalities i would not need to also import in AppModule. Thank you both